# Android canvas positioning, and customization

Tags: android, canvas, android-vectordrawable

So this is my scenario:

- I have an svg image that contains all the music notes on the staff (sort of sprite sheet)
- I have two svg image that contains the key (maybe i can merge them together anyway)

All of them are converted to android Vector Drawable.

What i want to do is to select the note from the first svg, select the cleff, and then show them next to each other (the two images should be aligned).

So what i managed to achieve is to select the portion of svg for the note (i need to refine the rect size). But what i'm still having problem is to show both of them on the same line.

```
public MusicScore(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        musicClef = (VectorDrawable) res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_bassclef, null);
        musicNotes = (VectorDrawable) res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_musicnotes, null);
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        Log.i("MUSIC", "H: " + musicClef.getMinimumHeight() + " W: " + musicClef.getMinimumWidth());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        Log.i("MUSIC", "Called");
        int left = getWidth()/2;
        int top = getHeight()/2;
        musicClef.setBounds(0,0,musicClef.getIntrinsicWidth(), musicClef.getIntrinsicHeight()   );

        Bitmap source = Bitmap.createBitmap(musicNotes.getIntrinsicWidth(), musicNotes.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Bitmap clefSource = Bitmap.createBitmap(musicClef.getIntrinsicWidth(), musicClef.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas newcanvas = new Canvas(source);
        Canvas clefCanvas = new Canvas(clefSource);
        int notesLeft = musicClef.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int notesTop = musicClef.getIntrinsicHeight();
        musicNotes.setBounds(0, 0, musicNotes.getIntrinsicWidth(), musicNotes.getIntrinsicHeight());
        musicNotes.draw(newcanvas);
        musicClef.draw(clefCanvas);
        Rect rect = new Rect(1150,0,1700, musicNotes.getIntrinsicHeight());
        Rect rect2 = new Rect(notesLeft ,0, notesLeft + 450, musicNotes.getIntrinsicHeight());
        Rect clefRect = new Rect(0, 0, musicClef.getIntrinsicWidth(), musicClef.getIntrinsicHeight());

        canvas.drawBitmap(clefSource, null, clefRect, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(source, rect, rect2, null);

    }
```

So with that code i can show a portion of the notes drawable, after converting it to a Bitmap. And i can also draw both of them, and the horizontal position is aligned. The problem is that the vertical position is not aligned, what i'm getting is:

[image: current output]

So i know that my code is not correct (i'm pretty new to canvas in android and trying to figure out what to do), and what i learned so far is:

- that in order to select a portion of the image i need to convert it to the Bitmap (i haven't found any way to do it directly with the VectorDrawable)
- While drawing a Bitmap on the canvas with DrawBitmap, the first Rect represents the portion area i want to show, and the second one is the size and position of the area displayed.
- In order to have the bitmap displayed on the canvas, i need to create a canvas from the Bitmap and draw it in it, in order to have it displayed. Is that correct?

So i have several questions:

- I would like to understand how to vertically align the images, so they have to start from the same y (top).
- I'm not sure if the vector image is the best idea, maybe is better to convert it into display dependant pngs? Or anyway the canvas size is relative to the screen? Or maybe i need to make my code screen-independent (i suppose that getIntrinsicWidth/Height are returning the real size of the image, so maybe i need to scale it?)
- Why I need to explicitly setBounds of both images to have them displayed?

UPDATE #1

So i understood why probably my images are not aligned on the same line. It looks like that when creating a vector asset, for some reason the sizes are "adapted", not sure if is the android systems doing that or android studio. But anyway what i found after loading two images with the same height in pixels, is that for one i have an height, and for the other i have a different height (nearly double), and that explain why the image is shifted on the bottom.

So what i tried is to make a single image with both the notes, and the clefs, and it sort of works in the emulator. But when testing on a real device i get the error:

> W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (11732x1168, max=8192x8192)
>       Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (11732x1168, max=8192x8192)

i can understand what the error means, but anyway the image size in pixel is: 2933x292 pixels. Why the getIntrinsicWidth and getIntrinsicHeight are returning that dimensions? what is their metrics?

I'm wondering that maybe the vector drawable is not the best choice? Maybe is better to cnvert it into screen-dependant pngs? and use them?